# complexity for nested loops

Tags: loops, big-o, complexity-theory, nested-loops, asymptotic-complexity

I am trying to figure out the complexity of a for loop using Big O notation. I have done this before in my other classes, but this one is more rigorous than the others because it is on the actual algorithm. The code is as follows:

```
for(i=n ; i>1 ; i/=2) //for any size n
{
    for(j = 1; j < i; j++)
    {
      x+=a
    }
}
```

and

```
for(i=1 ; i<=n;i++,x=1) //for any size n
{
    for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
      for(k = 1; k <= j; x+=a,k*=a)
      {

      }
    }
}
```

I have arrived that the first loop is of O(n) complexity because it is going through the list n times. As for the second loop I am a little lost!
Thank you for the help in the analysis. Each loop is in its own space, they are not together.

Comment: Is your comment in the last paragraph describing your thoughts on the first problem or the second one?

Comment: last paragraph describing the first problem

Comment: There is no list in your code, so I assume by "going through the list" you simply mean that `x += a` is executed `n` times, right? If so, how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: This may help http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4590/big-o-nested-for-loop-with-dependence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the first code fragment,

```
for(i=n ; i>1 ; i/=2) //for any size n
{
    for(j = 1; j < i; j++)
    {
      x+=a
    }
}
```

The instruction `x+=a` is executed for a total of  `n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1` times.

Sum of the first log<sub>2</sub>n terms of a G.P. with starting term `n` and common ratio `1/2` is, **(n (1-(1/2)<sup>log<sub>2</sub>n</sup>))/(1/2)**.  Thus the complexity of the first code fragment is **O(n)**.

Now consider the second code fragment,

```
for(i=1 ; i<=n; i++,x=1)
{
    for(j = 1; j <= i; j++)
    {
      for(k = 1; k <= j; x+=a,k*=a)
      {

      }
    }
}
```

The two outer loops together call the innermost loop a total of `n(n+1)/2` times. The innermost loop is executed at most `log<sub>a</sub>n` times. Thus the total time complexity of the second code fragment is **O(n<sup>2</sup>log<sub>a</sub>n)**.

Answer (score 1):

You may formally proceed like the following:

**Fragment 1:**

[image]

**Fragment 2** (Pochhammer, G-Function, and Stirling's Approximation)**:**

[image]

With [log(G(n))](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%28BarnesG%5Bn%5D%29).

**[UPDATE of Fragment 2]**:

With some enhancements from  "DISCRETE LOOPS AND WORST CASE PERFORMANCE" publication, by Dr. Johann Blieberger (All cases verified for **a = 2**):

[image]

Where:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Therefore,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I agree the first code block is *O*( n )

You decrement the outer loop `i` by diving by 2, and in the inner loop you run `i` times, so the number of iterations will be a sum over all the powers of two less than or equal to N but greater than 0, which is n<sup>log(n)+1</sup> - 1, so *O*(n).

The second code block is *O*(log<sub>a</sub>(n)n<sup>2</sup>) assuming `a` is a constant.

The two outermost loops equate to a sum of all the numbers less than or equal to n, which is n(n-1)/2, so *O*(n<sup>2</sup>). Finally the inner loop is the powers of a less than an upper bound of n, which is *O*(log<sub>a</sub>n).

Comment: can you please more expling why O(2log(n))

Comment: `2^log_2(n)` is just `n`, but I don't think you're right here. I'm pretty sure it actually is `O(n)`.