# What's the Big-Oh for nested loops i=0..n-2, j=i+1..n-1?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Given the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
{
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
    {
        // Do work.
    }
}
```

What is the Big-Oh value for it (over `n`)? I'm thinking it's O(N^2) but I'm not sure.

I did find a similar question here: [complexity for nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743395/complexity-for-nested-loops)

but it's not quite the same I think.

Comment: Well, can you derive an expression for how many times "do work" is executed?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth If I could, I wouldn't be asking! :)

Comment: You should try a few different values of `n` by hand, and see what the pattern is...

Comment: Is this really off-topic for SO? Why do we have a `big-o` tag then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's `O(N^2)`. Pair up the iterations of the inner loop in the beginning and at the end of the outer loop, like this:

The inner loop will execute...

- `N-1` times on the first iteration of the outer loop, and `1` time on the last iteration
- `N-2` times on the second iteration of the outer loop, and `2` times on the second to last iteration
- `N-3` times on the third iteration of the outer loop, and `3` times on the third to last iteration
- ... and so on; you will have `N/2` pairs like that; when `N` is odd, the last pair is incomplete.

You can see that each of the pairs executes a total of `N` times, and you have `N/2` such pairs, for a total of `N*(N-1)/2` times.

The way the formula is derived comes from the [derivation of the formula for the sum of arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Derivation) with the common difference of `1`.

Comment: Thanks; I suspected as much, but when asking my colleagues they weren't sure.

Comment: I'm selecting this as the answer because I prefer the mathematical solution over an empirical one.

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to check it this way.

```
int z = 0, n = 10; // try 20 etc
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
{
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
    {
        z++;
    }
}
```

Now, check the value of z.

```
With n = 10; z becomes 45
With n = 20; z becomes 190
With n = 40; z becomes 780
```

A doubling in **n** caused **z** to become ~4 times its value. Hence, it is approximately `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Aye, I guess I can do it empirically. I wonder if there's a proper mathematical proof though.

Answer (score 0):

Methodically, using Sigma notation (empirically verified), you can obtain the exact number of iterations plus the order of growth complexity:

[image]